How do I read CommandResult in a script file?
I am trying to detect when a potion of a specific type is drunk with a script file. I’m still experimenting with how and am trying to use testfor @s[hasitem={type=potion,location=slot.weapon.mainhand,data=22}] and use CommandResult as a way of detecting the type of potion, which in the case of data=22 is health 2. My full code is:
import {world, system, ItemStack} from "@minecraft/server";

const beforeEvents = world.beforeEvents;
const afterEvents = world.afterEvents;

let potionType = 0

afterEvents.itemStartUse.subscribe ((data) => {
    const type = data.itemStack.typeId
    const player = data.source
    
    let hasHealth2 = player.runCommand(`testfor @s[hasitem={item=potion,location=slot.weapon.mainhand, data=22}]`)
    
    console.warn("type = " + type + ", Has health 2 = " + hasHealth2.CommandResult + ", player = " + player.name)
})

Which results in:
[Scripting][warning]-type = minecraft:potion, Has health 2 = undefined, player = Ekipsogel

